# parse.com How to populate User object pointers?

Tags: parse-platform

How do we populate pointers in the User object? In my Parse User table, I have the following array of pointers: "toys", that points to an object of type "Toy".

In my iOS client:

`PFUser.currentUser()?.toys` will return an array of pointers to toys, not full Toy objects. **How do I retrieve and persists the full objects into `PFUser.currentUser()?.toys`** so that the next time I access `PFUser.currentUser()?.toys`, I get full objects?

Thanks.

**UPDATE:**

Sample code that shows what i mean (thanks Chaitanya Shah):

```
let query = PFUser.query()!
query.includeKey("toys")
query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(PFUser.currentUser()!.objectId!, block: {
    (object: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if object != nil {
            if let toys = object!["toys"] as? [PFObject] {
                println(toys) // full Toy objects
                println(PFUser.currentUser()?.toys) // Toy pointers
                // the two toys above won't be the same. What I want is
                // to have PFUser.currentUser() contains fully fetched toys
                // objects so I can use it throughout my app later without
                // have to re-fetch them.
            })
        }
 })
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let query = PFUser.query()!
query.includeKey("toys")
query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(PFUser.currentUser()!.objectId!, block: {
    (object: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if object != nil {
            if let toys = object!["toys"] as? [PFObject] {
                // toys!
            })
        }
 })
```

Comment: Yes, but if you access `PFUser.currentUser()!.toys` it's still an array of pointers, which is the essence of my question.

Comment: @VanDuTran , this answer is correct, but weak because it contains no explanation.  The essential part is `query.includeKey("toys")`, which causes the query to also fetch the related objects referred to by the pointers in the toys array.

Comment: @danh I understand the `query.includeKey("toys")`. However, the `PFObject?/PFUser?` returned by `query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId()` is NOT the same as `PFUser.currentUser()`, so after this method call, `PFUser.currentUser()!.toys` is still pointers not full objects. I will add more details to my original question.